# PHP comparing user input and stored data in XML file for login purpose

Tags: php, xml

I want to compare the user input from html file and compare it to XML file using PHP(XML is acting as database in this case, just for learning purpose). This is my current code
login.php

```
<?php
if(count($_POST) > 0)
{
$password = @trim($_POST["password"]);
$email = @trim($_POST["email"]);
$xml2 = file_get_contents('../../data/customer.xml');

if ((strpos($xml2, "<email>$email</email>") !== false) && (strpos($xml2, "<password>$password</password>") !== false))
{
    echo 'login succeeded';
    //$_SESSION["custno"] = $custno;
    $_SESSION['user']=(string) $customer->customerid;
    header("location:buying.htm");
}
else
{
    echo 'Wrong email or password';
}
}
?>
```

customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customer>
<user>
    <id>0</id>
    <fname>John</fname>
    <lname>Smith</lname>
    <email>jsmith@gmail.com</email>
    <password>jsmith</password>
    <phone>0412345677</phone>
</user>
<user>
    <id>1</id>
    <fname>Arthur</fname>
    <lname>Black</lname>
    <email>ablack@gmail.com</email>
    <password>ablack</password>
    <phone>0412345678</phone>
</user>
<user>
    <id>2</id>
    <fname>Brian</fname>
    <lname>Luo</lname>
    <email>bluo@gmail.com</email>
    <password>bluo</password>
    <phone>0412345678</phone>
</user>
</customer>
```

With the current code, any combination of existing email and password will go through. For example bluo@gmail.com with password jsmith will still pass the login page. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: Could you parse the xml and insert it into a db instead of using xml?

Comment: You should not try to parse xml by means of string functions. The whole point of xml is to be easily machine readable. So use an xml parser for this, that way you can code much more specific rules. Take a look at "simplexml": http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: I'm currently learning on how to use XML. No problem with db, I did login process with db before and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use the `SimpleXML` of PHP on this one:

```
$email = 'bluo@gmail.com';
$password = 'bluo';
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file('../../data/customer.xml');
foreach($xml2->user as $user) { // for every user node
    if($user->email == $email && $user->password == $password) {
        echo 'Yahoo';
    }
}
```

Or with using xpath:

```
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file('../../data/customer.xml');
$check = $xml2->xpath("//user[email='$email' and password='$password']");
if(count($check) > 0) {
    echo 'Yahoo';
}
```